# approach vs confront vs encounter

Tags: meaning, verbs, differences, synonyms, connotation

I know the difference between these verbs, however, I want to know if there are any other words meaning: *to approach someone by chance / to stumble upon someone.*

I once used *confront* like this:

> I confronted two Japanese fellows today. (I met them by chance)

And my American friend noted that *confront* (and also *accost*) are in an aggressive manner; and that I ought to use *approach* instead.

Are there any other verbs or expressions with the same meaning, except for  *approach*, *come across,* and *bump into*?

Comment: There is also nothing wrong with the word you suggest in the title of your question. *I* ***encountered*** *someone* is perfectly reasonable. It implies chance without planning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the US, its fairly common to say "I ran into my friend Joe on the way to the store".  It has no negative connotations and indicates a random encounter.  See [this](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/run-into-sb) in Cambridge.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, please add a source to support your answer. While it's a fairly common expression, it may help future visitors.